# Google OpenID is going away - do I need to worry?

Tags: discussion, google, openid

[image: Google warning about OpenIDs]

Is Stack Overflow affected, and should I be switching over authentication methods?

Comment: [“OpenID 2.0 for Google Accounts is going away”; will this affect Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244367/openid-2-0-for-google-accounts-is-going-away-will-this-affect-stack-exchange)

Comment: @animuson: why not flag or close as duplicate?

Comment: @ThomasW. That link is to a question on MSE, which is a completely different site from MSO. You can only VTC as a duplicate if the target is on the same site.

Comment: I break the system every time. :|